# Can i get a SQL Server catch Updates to reflect the responsible objectid with a database trigger?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, trigger, constraint

I have a table that runs several stored procedures and stores the resulting rows in the target table `[TestTable]`

`[TestTable]` is first populated by the stored procedure `[spInsertRowToTestTable]` and then Updated by `[spUpdatesRowInTestTableFirst]` and `[spUpdatesRowInTestTableLast]`

I can capture the responsible procedure of initial insert in the table by using a Default Constatraint to set the `@@PROCID`. I would like to capture Updates in a similar way, without modifying existing procedures that result in updates to the row.

I have tried, but I have not been able to create a trigger or a similar solution that captures any subsequent Updates. The scope of the calling procedure aludes my atempts to catch it in a trigger and update the row.

Is there a straight forward way to do this?

See example code below:

```
--DROP SCHEMA test;
--GO
--DROP TABLE test.TestTable;
CREATE SCHEMA test;
GO

CREATE TABLE test.TestTable
    (
      Column1 NVARCHAR(20) NULL ,
      RowInsertedBySP NVARCHAR(30)
        NULL
        CONSTRAINT DF_TestTable_RowInsertedBySP DEFAULT OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) ,
      RowUpdatedBY NVARCHAR(20)
    );
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE test.spInsertRowToTestTable
AS
    INSERT  INTO test.TestTable
            ( Column1 )
    VALUES  ( 'TestRow' );
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE test.spUpdatesRowInTestTableFirst
AS
    UPDATE test.TestTable
    SET Column1 = 'Updated ' +[Column1]; 
GO

EXEC test.spInsertRowToTestTable;

SELECT  *
FROM    test.TestTable AS tt;
```

Resulting in:

```
Column1              RowInsertedBySP                RowUpdatedBY
-------------------- ------------------------------ --------------------
TestRow              spInsertRowToTestTable         NULL

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I would simply like to catch the ids of the procedures that do Updates on the rows in column `[RowUpdatedBy]`.

i.e if i have `[spUpdatesRowInTestTableFirst]`, `[spUpdatesRowInTestTableLast]`. The column `[RowUpdatedBy]` should then reflect the updates like this:

```
Column1              RowInsertedBySP                RowUpdatedBY
-------------------- ------------------------------ --------------------
TestRow              spInsertRowToTestTable        spUpdatesRowInTestTableFirst, spUpdatesRowInTestTableLast
```

I have seen a example of using DBCC Outputbuffer, but i would rather not go down that road. We use Enterprise edition, so another idea would be to leverage CDC.

I would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know who wrote what and when,
I would create 2 users, one for each of the procedures involved, and then 
[create procedures with execute as user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx)

add an extra column on your testtable to keep the session_user or current_user so that you know who inserted/updated each record since insert_procedure will be executed as insert_user and update_procedure will be executed as update_user.

this script can help you to find out the original login, and compares different ways of addressing the users.

```
DECLARE @User VARCHAR(20)
SELECT @USER = SUBSTRING(SUSER_SNAME(), 
               CHARINDEX('\', 
               SUSER_SNAME()) + 1, 
               LEN(SUSER_SNAME()))


SELECT   @USER 
        , SUSER_SNAME()
        ,SYSTEM_USER
        , USER_NAME()
        , CURRENT_USER
        , ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
        ,USER
        ,SESSION_USER


EXECUTE AS LOGIN='my_user'

--DECLARE @User VARCHAR(20)
SELECT @USER = SUBSTRING(SUSER_SNAME(), 
               CHARINDEX('\', 
               SUSER_SNAME()) + 1, 
               LEN(SUSER_SNAME()))


SELECT   @USER 
        , SUSER_SNAME()
        ,SYSTEM_USER
        , USER_NAME()
        , CURRENT_USER
        , ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
        , USER
        ,SESSION_USER

REVERT
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i would however like to find a solution that does not require me to change any of the Updating procedures, much like how i catch the Inserting procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve the same result without using trigger. You can simply make a small change to your update proc as shown below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test.spUpdatesRowInTestTableFirst
AS
    UPDATE test.TestTable
    SET Column1 = 'Updated ' +[Column1]
    , RowUpdatedBY = isnull(RowUpdatedBY, '') + object_name(@@procid) +',' -- adding this line to record the update
GO
```

But we need to EXPAND your table's [RowUpdateBy] column from current nvarchar(20) to NVARCHAR(2000) to avoid issue.

Comment: Yes that is of course a option. But this was a simple example, and i am looking for a solution that does not requoire me to update all the proceedures. But rather capture it via a trigger or the table itself.

Comment: @Viggos, I think your question is similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467961/how-to-get-the-stored-procedure-name-from-a-trigger-when-an-update-operation-was?noredirect=1&lq=1
In short, there is no way for a trigger to know the name of a procedure that fires the trigger, but there is some not-reliable workaround as mentioned in the above link.

Comment: i am starting to settle on that fact also. I will probably end up running a modification on script on all the update statements. It would have been nice to capture it from the other side thou...